# How to remove/replace fonts currently in use

Tags: c#, fonts, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I'd like to deploy font packages programmatically during our update process. Therefore, I need to replace the old font files in `\Windows\Fonts` with the new ones extracted from a ZIP archive. Deleting an existing font file will cause an `IOException`, because of another process accessing the file.

I tried to release the font by calling [RemoveFontResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901142.aspx) and propagating the change with a [WM_FONTCHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, but no luck. `RemoveFontResource` returns `false` with native error 2 (file not found?) and HRESULT -2147467259. The file actually does exist.

Sample code:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int RemoveFontResource(string lpName);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WM_FONTCHANGE = 0x001D;
private const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;

public const string SAMPLE_FILE = @"\Windows\Fonts\MyFont.ttf";

public void RemoveFont()
{
  if (!RemoveFontResource(SAMPLE_FILE)) 
  {
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
  }

  SendMessage(new IntPtr(HWND_BROADCAST), WM_FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

  File.Delete(SAMPLE_FILE);
}
```

Is there actually a clean way to deploy and replace fonts system-wide?

Answer (score 2):

If the font files are part of the OS image, they have the eXecute-In-Place (XIP) attribute set (read-only, system, ROM) and cannot simply replaced. Although one can copy a file of the same name on top, which hides the original file. If the file copied on top is deleted, the original file is back. This is the case with all XIP files.

I recommend you use the SysCache dir to replace the files. This will work with all file replacements, regardless if they are XIP, drivers, DLLs, in-use or otherwise locked for replacement.

If you place files with the same name as the origibal file in the syscache dir, these will be used instead of the original files. But you have to warmboot the device after placing files in the syscache dir. Windows CE/Mobile will recognize and 'use' the syscache files only during the OS startup.

The location of the syscache dir may vary, depending on OS version and OEM decisions. On WM 6 devices it should be \Windows\System\syscache. Check the file system of the device for an existing syscache directory.

BTW: font files do not need to be placed into \Windows\Fonts, it is OK to place them in \Windows.

Comment: Actually it's a custom font that's not part of the OS image. I guess the problem is an application running in the foreground using the fonts while the background service attempts to replace them. Thanks for your hints on XIP-files, anyway. Are there any resources on the syscache directory on the web? I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: You should just esarch the web for "windows ce syscache" and you will find many resources (not only by me :-)).

Comment: I find a lot about VMWare, NHibernate, Windows 7 and Spring ... but no official MSDN article or a blog entry. However, I'll give it a try :)